# Como adicionar Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 ao instalador do meu aplicativo .NET?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, instalador, oledb

Olá, tenho um aplicativo que programei através do `Visual Studio 2017` que utiliza o `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` para fazer consultas em arquivos `Excel` e retornar dados.

Agora que finalizei o projeto precisei publicar.
Mas ao instalar o aplicativo em uma máquina que não tem o `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` instalado, o aplicativo dá um erro de conexão e não executa as tarefas corretamente.

Por isso estou querendo saber de alguma solução para isso, alguma forma de incluir esse pacote no instalador do aplicativo, ou outra forma de se corrigir o problema.

PS.:Utilizei o `Microsoft Office Access database engine 2007` instalado na minha máquina para poder utilizar o aplicativo com o `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`. Não sei se precisaria instalar isso na máquina do usuário final ou como adicionar isso ao instalador do `app`.

Estava tentando adicionar alguma referencia ou dll que solucionasse o problema, mas ainda não consegui.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Para tentar acessar um banco de dados `Access` ou uma planilha do `Excel` utilizando o `Visual Studio` você precisa instalar os seguintes softwares:

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255)

[2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734)

[Fonte](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-quotthe-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local?forum=vstsdb)

[Fonte 2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ebb05600-055a-44c4-8cd3-d33a79878b23/error-when-trying-to-connect-to-access-database?forum=csharpgeneral)